# Problems with intl.dll running GTK+ program

Tags: c, dll, gtk

When attempting to run a program built with GTK+ (e.g., GIMP, or gnuplot, or an app you're building with GTK+), the following error appears:

[image: Error message]

(The text reads: "The procedure entry point libintl_setlocale could not be located in the dynamic link library intl.dll")

The error will not always be "libintl_setlocale", it depends on what procedure your application is actually trying to invoke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely that a different version of the `intl.dll` library is being used than the one that the application requires. Applications built with GTK+ will frequently come with a copy of this library, and that copy should work, but that doesn't mean it's the one that Windows will load.

If the application *did* come with a copy of the library, it is likely placed in the applicatio'ns `bin` directory (for instance, in GIMP v2.0, it is found at `{GIMP_DIR}/32/bin/intl.dll`). So to get the application to run, you should make sure this is the library that your OS loads for the application.

There are various ways to do this:

1. The simplest is to put a copy of the library directly in the same directory as the application's executable. Windows always looks for DLLs *first* in the same directory as the executable [[ref]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18.aspx). The upside to this is that it shouldn't affect any other applications which may rely on a *different* version of the library.
2. Alternatively, you can try to track down the version of the library that is being incorrectly loaded. For instance, use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to inspect the application and find out which file is being loaded for `init.dll`. Once you find the file, you need to figure out some way to make sure that the desired copy is loaded instead of this one. For instance, place the desired copy somewhere higher on the library search path, [described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18.aspx). This may require replacing the undesired file with the desired one: **be very vareful** replacing DLLs, as it could break other applications that use it. *generally*, widely used DLLs maintain backwards compatibility, so when you get this error, it likely means that the found copy of the library is an older version, and the desired copy is a newer version that will still work. However, this is **far from a guarantee**, so always keep a backup copy of the DLL instead of overwriting it.